# Logitech K380 Bluetooth Keyboard Is Laggy

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, lag, logitech-keyboard

My Bluetooth Logitech K380 keyboard is laggy when it's connected to Windows 10 Enterprise (20H2) Dell laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

- Go to Control **Panel > Devices and Printers**
- Right-click on **Keyboard K380** and click on **Properties**
- Go to the **Hardware** tab
- Select **Bluetooth HID Device** from the list and click on **Properties**
- Click on **Change settings**
- Go to the **Prower Management** tab
- Uncheck **Allow the computer to turn off the device to save power**
- Restart